# Page Break in C# Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In my C# .Net windows application am using crystal reports to print employee information.Am using Roll Paper (A4) for printing purpose.Here when i print the report,its  working fine.My issue is that if the table contains only one row of record,it takes  the whole page to print there is no page break. ,i mean the whole A4 paper to print the report.But i  need only a small portion of the same.How to put page break and remove the white blank space after the report.  .[image: Report][image]

Comment: try supressing the sections producing the blank spaces.

Comment: Do you mean suppress the extra spacing in the `details` section or at the end of the report?  Is there grouping?  Do you force a new page after each group?  Please post a screenshot of the report in design mode so I can see which sections are involved.

Comment: On the client machines (where the roll paper printer is installed), you should be able to select that printer from the Page Setup menu. That _should_ allow you to control the roll paper options... do you not see any of these options (For example, an option on where to cut the page)?

Comment: @craig i didnt used any group.Its just a simple report that only three  or four fields are there and its size was 4" x 6" .Am using Epson LX 300 II for printing purpose.

Comment: @Ryan its size was 4" x 6" .Am using Epson LX 300 II for printing purpose.All are set to custom size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem.it is not a one sided problem even if the records are more than A4 page capacity then your print will not be printed in single piece.
Crystal Report does not support dynamic paper size and roll printing does not have fixed paper height. so, using crystal report you could not place page break at the end of your report data.
You have to create your code to print your report if the report structure is not complicated.  I don't know much about microsoft reporting tool. i think microsoft reporting tool may help you.